# Lower Triangular Matrix equal to value in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to find a lower triangular matrix in Julia and place that matrix in a zeros matrix (replacing the zeros). I then want to set the lower triangular matrix equal to the value c. In R this would look something like this:

```
mat <- matrix(0, n,n)
mat[lower.tri(mat, diag=FALSE)] <- c
```

with an output that looks like this:

```
          [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.0000000    0
[2,] 0.4646787    0
```

I am able to make the zeros matrix in Julia, but I do not know how to place the lowertriangular function inside of the it along with the c value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's probably the closest equivalent in Julia:

```
julia> n = 3; c = 0.4646787; A = zeros(n,n);

julia> A[tril!(trues(size(A)), -1)] .= c;

julia> A
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0       0.0       0.0
 0.464679  0.0       0.0
 0.464679  0.464679  0.0
```

Of course, one of the big advantages in Julia is that you don't need to worry about creating these clever one-liners nearly as much.  Writing out the naive `for` loops is quite easy and should have similar performance:

```
julia> for j in 1:size(A, 2), i in j+1:size(A, 1)
           A[i, j] = c
       end

julia> A
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0       0.0       0.0
 0.464679  0.0       0.0
 0.464679  0.464679  0.0
```

Comment: An excellent answer! A similar idea which is a bit simpler is `tril!(fill(c, n, n), -1)`.